# Memory allocation of python object

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
a = 2
b = a

a = a + 2
print (a)
print (b)
```

My question is why does b print out as 2 and not 4? If you assign a to b, doesn't b always reference to the memory of a?

Thanks

Comment: No, Python variables are not locations in memory. please read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Comment: Fundamentally, Python **is not C**. Variables are *not locations in memory*, and assignment, and re-assignment are not related to memory allocation. Memory allocation is a red-herring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable gets re-allocated to a new address when you re-assign `a`:

```
>>> a = 2
>>> b = a
# get memory address for a and b
>>> id(a)
4357961072
>>> id(b)
4357961072
# they are the same

# now reassign
>>> a = a + 2
# id of a has changed
>>> id(a)
4357961136
# id of b has not
>>> id(b)
4357961072
```

Comment: It is not the assignment which re-allocates memory, it is not even useful to think of python variable assignments in terms of memory allocation, indeed here, in CPython, *all the objects being referenced were already allocated* and no new objects have been created

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id), it explains that id reflects the *the address of the object in memory.*, so doesn't the memory address of the variable change?

Comment: Yes `id` happens to give you the address of an object. But you never created any object, and the point is all of this has nothing to do with the *semantics of variable assignment*, which is the fundamental problem here. My point is, as it happens, in CPython, small ints are *allocated* when the interpreter starts up. All the `int` objects are already allocated. *Memory allocations is a red-herring*, Python variables are not like C variables. The *variable* doesn't get "realocated", the variable *is literally a key in a dict*, and neither does the object.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga You're correct, I'm changing the answer to reflect your point.

Comment: @sacul Your link also says that the use of a memory address is a CPython implementation detail; it's not something required or specified by the language itself. PyPy, Jython, IronPython, etc. are all free to return something else from `id`.

Comment: Thanks all for the input, I'm clearly missing something. @Nant, can you un-accept this answer so I can delete it?

Comment: @sacul you're not wrong, you said it gets reallocated when re-assign happen, and that's exactly what happened. even if you reassign `5` to `5`, it still tries to find that allocation which just happen to be in the same location which has already been allocated.

Comment: To be precise, `a + 2` evaluates to *an* object. It may be the same object as `a` (unlikely, but it depends on how `type(a).__add__` is implemented), it may be an existing object (CPython, for example, preallocates `int` objects between -5 and 256), or it may indeed be a brand new object created on the spot.

Comment: @RockyLi no, *reallocation and assignment are not directly related*. The fundamental misunderstanding here is that python variables work like C-variables, that they are essentially memory locations of some size.

Answer (score 3):

Because you have reassigned x to a new location by `x = x + 1`, and it's not about immutability.

For checking:

```
x = 2
y = x

>>> id(x), id(y)
(26726784, 26726784) # same
```

Then, change this:

```
x = x+1

>>> id(x), id(y)
(26726760, 26726784) # not same, because x reassigned to a new reference location.
```

If you do the same for `list`, which are mutable, you'll have the same result:

```
x=[5]
y=x

>>> id(x), id(y)
(139890260976056, 139890260976056)
```

on assignment:

```
x = x + [5]

>>> id(x), id(y)
(139890260094344, 139890260976056) # not same, id reallocated on assignment
>>> x, y
([5, 5], [5])
```

You'll see mutable behavior on list by using `x.append(5)`, where both x and y change as you're modifying the object itself. But in this case, it's not the mutability of the object that are causing the difference. It's the assignment `x=something else` that changed the reference.

An interesting property about `int` in python is that smaller ones are pre-allocated. For instance, if you do:

```
x = 5
y = x
x = 5
id(x) == id(y) # True
```

The id will be the same, however, if you do:

```
x = 5000000000000
y = x
x = 5000000000000 # same as previous.
id(x) == id(y) # False
```

This is due to small integers having pre-allocated location while large ones don't. As such reassignment for large integer will find a different location instead.

This validates @juanpa.arrivillaga's point that this is due to assignment, not immutability.

Comment: I wouldn't even say "location", because Python doesn't say *anything* about how objects are implemented. Rather, the name `x` is simply bound to the object that `x + 1` evaluates to, whatever that object might be. More often than not, `x + 1` is a different (not necessarily *new*) object than what `x` referred to. (For example, it's entirely possible that `type(x).__add__` could simply return a mutated version of `x` for whatever reason. `int.__add__`, of course, does not.)

Comment: Would you say *(potential) new reference* instead?

Answer (score 0):

Not all python objects are mutable, here's list of which are.

[image]

Comment: Mutability here is completely irrelevant.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga It's tangentially relevant but additional information is needed

Comment: @Woody1193 no, it is completely irrelevant. The semantics of assignment do not change based on the types of the objects.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is correct, assignment is exactly the same for all objects.

Comment: Disagree. If `a` and `b` in the OP's question were lists then the outcome would be completely different. The reason `b` is not updated is related to integers being immutable in Python. The explanation for that link is not contained in this answer but, with elaboration, this information would be relevant.

Comment: @Woody1193 *try it with lists* and you'll see you are *wrong*.